# Batch - Delete all folders and their contents EXCEPT ONE FOLDER

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder called 'Parent'. I want to delete everything in 'Parent': files, folders, everything EXCEPT Folder named 'Keep' and its contents.
I've been fiddling with this for a while but I just can't figure it out, mostly because I have no clue how batch works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir c:\parent /b /s /a-d ^|find /v /i "\keep\"') do del "%%a
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir c:\parent /b /s /ad  ^|find /v /i "\keep" ^|sort /r ') do rd "%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Robocopy for this: create an empty folder such as `mkdir c:\a` then mirror that with the folder you want to delete and use the exclude directory flag (/xd) to keep the folder you don't want to delete `robocopy /mir c:\a c:\parent /xd keep`